# Function that iterates over tables called programmatically

Tags: postgresql

I need a function that uses an identifier to choose dos tables and returns another table with process values from those tables.

Let consider these tables:

table *sum1_suffix*

```
 id | digit1 
----+--------
  1 |      2
  2 |      8
  3 |      7
  4 |      5
```

table *sum2_suffix*

```
 id | digit2 
----+--------
  1 |      7
  2 |      3
  3 |      9
  4 |      1
```

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add(IN tablesuffix character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(result integer) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    var_r record;
    tabla_s1 character varying;
    tabla_s2 character varying;
    cadena_sql TEXT; --for debugging
BEGIN
 tabla_s1 := quote_ident(CONCAT('sum1_',tablesuffix));
 tabla_s2 := quote_ident(CONCAT('sum2_',tablesuffix));
EXECUTE     
--cadena_sql :=
 'FOR var_r IN( SELECT ' || 
        tabla_s1 ||'.digit1 , '||tabla_s2 ||'.digit2 
   FROM '||tabla_s1||','||tabla_s2||
 ' WHERE '||tabla_s1||'.id ='|| tabla_s2||'.id)
 LOOP
        result := var_r.digit1 + var_r.digit2
        RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;';
 RAISE NOTICE 'cadena sql es %',cadena_sql;
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.add(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Finally, I call the function:

```
select * from add('suffix');
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOR"
LINE 1: FOR var_r IN( SELECT sum1_code.digit1 , sum2_code.digit2 
        ^
```

Also I have try to modify this line:

```
'FOR var_r IN(SELECT ' ||
```

in this way:

```
'FOR '||var_r ||' IN(SELECT ' ||
```

But then I get the next error:

```
ERROR:  record "var_r" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 'FOR '||var_r ||' IN(SELECT ' || 
...........
```

(N.B. I haven't used FORMAT() into EXECUTE because in the real query I have about 20 *I%* arguments and it's more readable for me don't use this way, at least until I have fixed the main problem.)

Comment: You are mixing up SQL and PL/pgSQL. `FOR` is no SQL statement, so you cannot run it with `EXECUTE`. But you can use `FOR var_r IN EXECUTE ...`.

Comment: Minor hint: learn how to use the `format()` function. It could simplify your code a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that there are several errors in the function:

**First**

You can not use control structure with `EXECUTE`

```
EXECUTE     
--cadena_sql :=
 'FOR var_r IN( SELECT ' || 
        tabla_s1 ||'.digit1 , '||tabla_s2 ||'.digit2 
   FROM '||tabla_s1||','||tabla_s2||
 ' WHERE '||tabla_s1||'.id ='|| tabla_s2||'.id)
 LOOP
        result := var_r.digit1 + var_r.digit2
        RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;';
```

**Second**

There is no `+` operator for the character type varying.

```
result := var_r.digit1 + var_r.digit2
```

**Considering those points, maybe this will work**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add(IN tablesuffix character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(result integer) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    var_r record;
    tabla_s1 character varying;
    tabla_s2 character varying;
    cadena_sql TEXT; --for debugging
BEGIN
 tabla_s1 := quote_ident(CONCAT('sum1_',tablesuffix));
 tabla_s2 := quote_ident(CONCAT('sum2_',tablesuffix));

--cadena_sql :=
 FOR var_r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || 
        tabla_s1 ||'.digit1 , '||tabla_s2 ||'.digit2 
   FROM '||tabla_s1||','||tabla_s2||
 ' WHERE '||tabla_s1||'.id ='|| tabla_s2||'.id'
 LOOP
        result := var_r.digit1::int + var_r.digit2::int;
        RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;
 RAISE NOTICE 'cadena sql es %',cadena_sql;
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.add(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```